# Are we able to convert an absolute reference to a "custom reference"?

Tags: excel, vba

When using FindAll, we are given a list of absolute references of where the string is found. (eg. $B$4) Is it possible to customize this reference using VBA in which instead of returning a $B$4, I can convert it to say "Tray 1, Position 4"?

Below is a little more context to this question:

- This excel sheet contains sheets with titles "Tray 1, Tray 2, ..."
- Each Tray holds about 50 values in Range("B4:B54") and Range("D4:D54") that may need to be searched.
- When searched, the absolute reference may not be quick and easy to understand with users not familiar with excel.

I am trying to find a way to convert these absolute references into easy to digest locations.

So far I've only used the built-in CTRL + F function but I'm open to trying VBA.

Comment: So B is Tray 1 and C is Tray 2?

Comment: You can use the `Column` function and just offset by 1 to get desired effect

Comment: Clicking any entry in the "find all" results takes you directly to that value, and the sheet name is listed - isn't that enough?  You can't modify the results in the built-in dialog, so you'd need to recreate that as a custom userform and use VBA to perform the search.

Comment: Are you looking for Named Ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
="Tray " & COLUMN(B4) - 1 & " Position " & ROW(B4)
```

You can try something like this. It will offset the Column by 1 (B = 1, C = 2, etc.) and return the row number as well

Comment: Thanks! I didn't quite use this code but your idea of the offset worked perfectly!

Comment: Just realized my equation had typos - updated it. Glad you got it figured out